# Best way to set up a common enviornment for using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to work on a ruby on rails project with a group of 4 people. If we install rails 4.2.0 how can we ensure that we all share the same environment? Is the only option to have install VM? or is there some other way? I mean what if one user is using mac another is on windows and another is on Linux? How can we ensure all are having same environment so there is no configuration issues etc? What is the easiest solution?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, I think. Do you just mean the same database, or do you have external dependencies? Usually making sure you use a SCM tool and Bundler correctly, you should all have the same environment. If your concern is more OS, then a VM like Vagrant or Docker may be your best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MarcBaumbach stated above tools like [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com), [Docker](http://dev.chaione.com/rapid-rails-setup-with-docker-and-fig/) and [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com) are built for this. In my experience your environment do not need to be identical. I work on a Mac at work, Fedora at home and I have a teammate in India who uses Ubuntu. Specifying the Ruby version as well as the Rails version in the gemfile works well.

## Gemfile

```
ruby '2.2.0'

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
```

Comment: One of my group member is insisting we all download VM so we have identical vdi image or else it will be an issue. I am new to rails so i wanted to make sure if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean what if one user is using mac another is on windows and another
>   is on Linux?

Well, I'd advise you to not use local development machine then. Use [Cloud 9 IDE](https://c9.io/), which literally creates an environment for you to work with and it's cross-browser.

You need not install anything as it's taken care by it.

Comment: Is there some free solution available ?

Comment: @Learner afaik, I don't know of any free solution to this.

Comment: @Learner I haven't used it but you may want to look at  [Runnable](http://runnable.com)